# How to specify link text when the link is an image?

Tags: text, seo, hyperlink, banner

I'm making an web shop (my first one), and on the front page my client wants banners with their current hot deals. Naturally I want Google and other robots to be able to understand what these links are all about. I think (but I'm not sure) that Google will treat my `<a>` tag better if it will have some relevant text inside it. But a banner is just an image. How do I put text there? Could a `<span style="display:none">` work? Maybe the `title=""` attribute?

**Added:** OOps, forgot to say - I place the image as a background image to my `<a>` tag - this gives me vertical centering. So there are no `<img>` tags.

Comment: I've always done `<a href="whatever.html"><span style="display:none;">My SEO text</span></a>`. I've learned this trick from the [CSSZenGarden](http://www.csszengarden.com). Another way to "hide" text involve setting a `text-indent: -100000em;`, and I'm sure there are some more.

Comment: @Carlos Campderrós - Could you post that as an answer? And - do you have any evidence that this works?

Comment: I think any text you deliberately try to "Hide" is considered spamming by Google and might cause you more damage than actual results.

Comment: @Pleun - yes, that's what I'm afraid of. Currently I put the text in the `title` attribute. I suppose that should count for something. :P

Answer (score 2):

Google will index the Alt text property on your image.
http://www.search-marketing.info/organic-listings/img-alt.htm

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Forgot to say that the image is a background image to the `<a>` tag, not an actual `<img>` element. I do this to get vertical centering.

Comment: Maybe I should include an actual `<img>` tag and then style it to be invisible? Is google aware of `style="display:none"`?

Answer (score 0):

I've always done `<a href="whatever.html"><span style="display:none;">My SEO text</span></a>`. I've learned this trick from the CSSZenGarden. Another way to "hide" text involve setting a `text-indent: -100000em;`, and I'm sure there are some more.

It works at the CSS Zen Garden, google does not penalize it. search for ["the beauty of css design"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%22the+beauty+of+css+design%22) and you'll see that it gets indexed at google.

Answer (score -1):

Google cant crawl images but Google can index alt text so try to link the images with alt-abbr.